# Do they check for herpes during the medical exam for a visa for Germany?

Tags: working-visas, germany, medical

I am a doctor planning to apply for a specialization in surgery in Germany. I have just been  diagnosed as herpes positive during a checkup.

During the visa-required medical examination, I know that they usually check for HIV, hepatitis B and C, TB, syphilis and gonorrhea.

I found that, in the US, having herpes is not considered an issue when applying for similar placement.

I am unable to determine whether it is of concern for Germany.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's specific to clinicians, a better fit on [Health](https://health.stackexchange.com/).